# Ratio & Mixture

Tags: algebra-precalculus

In what ratio $3$ solutions (of milk and water $A,B,C$ ) are to be mixed to get a resultant solution $1:1$ ratio milk and water? 
In solution $A$ milk:water $=2:3$,
in solution $B$ milk:water $=1:3$,
and in Solution $C$ milk:water $=5:1$.

**Answer : Cannot be determined.**

**My Approach:**
1st mix $A,C$ to get milk:water $\rightarrow 1:1$
By alligation $A:C =10:3$
2nd Mix $B,C$ to get milk:water $\rightarrow 1:1$
By alligation $B:C=4:3$
Then $A:B:C=10:4:3$ but the answer is 'Cannot be determined'.
Cannot understand what is the mistake here.

Answer (score 0):

In solution $A$, there is $\frac25$ water and $\frac 35$ milk. Solution $B$ is $\frac14$ water and $\frac34$ milk, and solution $C$ is $\frac 56$ water and $\frac 16$ milk.

Now, say I have numbers $x,y,z$ which determine how much of which solution I mix. Of course, the three numbers must add to $1$ (for example, I can make a new solution which is $\frac 12$ solution $A$, $\frac 13$ solution $B$ and $\frac 16$ solution $C$).

What is the amount of water and milk in the new solution? Well $x$ parts of the solution come from $A$, which has $\frac 25$ water, so this gives $x\cdot\frac 25$ amount of water. Solution $B$ similarly brings $\frac14\cdot y$ amount of water, and $C$ brings $z\cdot \frac 56$. Together, the amoun of water is

$$\frac25 x + \frac 14 y + \frac56 z$$
so if this equation is equal to $\frac 12$, the glass will be half water. There exists an infinite number of solutions for this, since you know that $x+y+z =1$, you can pick an arbitrary $x$, you can find a solution for $$\frac 25x + \frac 14(1-z) + \frac 56 z = \frac 12$$

Comment: OK . I think I understand the mistake in my approach.Since I am taking both (A,C) & (B,C) mixture to contain 1:1 Milk:water, I can mix them(the 2 resultant mixtures) in any ratio.And each will have a different solution. Is my understanding correct?